.NET 7 multiple concurrent HTTP requests blocking each other (threadpool contention?)
I have an application that queries a large number of separate systems to check user access status. For each system, it typically requires requesting an access token and then making one or more requests to the back end system to check if a user is configured. Each system's check are independent of each other. All the calls are async. I have tried to ensure all calls have .ConfigureAwait(false).  I suspect there is contention on the thread pool when the requests complete. I know the thread pool is initialized based on the CPU count and the thread pool injection algorithm can take a while inject new threads.
OpenTelemetry Trace of one request: 

running on OpenShift (Kubernetes)
tried adjusting the resource request and limits (req: 500m cpu, 512Mi memory, limit: 4 cpu, 2Gi memory)
cpu: Xeon Gold 6244 (8 core, 16 thread) - cluster is heterogeneous
low concurrent users using the app (one or two)

I have tried to configure the runtime by using a AppAssemblyName.runtimeconfig.json like this:
      {
        "runtimeOptions":{
          "tfm":"net7.0",
          "frameworks":[
            {
              "name":"Microsoft.NETCore.App",
              "version":"7.0.0"
            },
            {
              "name":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
              "version":"7.0.0"
            }
          ],
          "configProperties": {
            "System.GC.Server": true,
            "System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdater.IsSupported": false,
            "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false,
            "System.Threading.ThreadPool.MinThreads": 4,
            "System.Threading.ThreadPool.Blocking.ThreadsToAddWithoutDelay_ProcCountFactor": 2
          }
        }

Is the best way just to bump up System.Threading.ThreadPool.MinThreads higher?
The code is on github (https://github.com/bcgov/maltd/tree/main/src/BcGov.Jag.AccountManagement)

Have you tested what happens if you increase the System.Threading.ThreadPool.MinThreads? Does this solve the problem?

Possibly the backend database is overloaded? Also if you use both access and refresh tokens then that puts less load on the Access Server as it only checks the database when the refresh token is renewed.

Don't get the Frontend and Backend confused.  The HTXML connection is probably the Frontend.  You need to increase the timeout in the backend to the database.  Normally the default time for a database query is 30 seconds.


Possibly the backend database is overloaded? Also if you use both access and refresh tokens then that puts less load on the Access Server as it only checks the database when the refresh token is renewed.

Each service is independent. separate database servers.


Don't get the Frontend and Backend confused. The HTXML connection is probably the Frontend. You need to increase the timeout in the backend to the database. Normally the default time for a database query is 30 seconds.

These calls are all back end calls. The screen shot is just Jaeger (OpenTelemetry).
